# Python platform on M1 confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, apple-m1

Apologies if this is a dumb question, but after having some problems with python packaging I ran `platform.machine()` on my M1 Mac, expecting the output to be `arm64` as I had seen online but instead got `x86_64` which is the Intel processor. I just don't understand how this could be the case on this machine, so any explanation would be super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

What python are you using? If you are on `< Python 3.9`, which is most likely, then the python interpreter is made for an `x86 Intel Processor`, which was translated using `Rosetta 2`. Now, there is no problem with having an `x86` Python Interpreter, actually, it's probably best to not use the newest versions of Python, as there might be some errors.

If you go to the official `python.org` website, you can see there are two different downloads: One for the ARM Macbooks and another for the Intel Macbooks. You may have installed the Intel Download for Python 3.9.2, which is why you are getting this output.

Comment: I thought that could be the case but it’s 3.9.2

Comment: Check which version of Python 3.9 you are using. If you go to the official python.org website, you can see there are two different downloads: One for the ARM Macbooks and another for the Intel Macbooks. You may have installed the Intel Download for Python 3.9.2

Comment: You mean on ARM Mac, we can use Python Intel version ? On Intel Mac, can we use Python ARM version ?

Comment: @Philippe Since the new M1's are new, Apple has incorporated Rosetta 2 so that you can still run applications built for Intel Macs. I don't know if you can run ARM Python on an Intel Mac, but I know that you can run Intel python on an ARM Mac (I am using Python 3.8, which is only built for intel). Rosetta 2 is surprisingly effective, so I don't see any downside of using Intel Apps on an ARM Mac, except for it being ever-so-slightly slower.